# Terminal width IOCTL when piped to less

Tags: terminal, ioctl, less-unix

I have this program which uses

```
ioctl(file_descriptor_of_stdout, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
```

to get the terminal width (used in printing arrays). This works fine if I run my program directly on a terminal; however, I often pipe output through less, for paging and searching. For the sake of discussion assume stderr is also piped, so I can't "cheat" by expecting that to actually go to the terminal.

Now, less itself *does* take account of the terminal's width - for breaking lines or chopping them off. Does it not communicate this information further somehow to whatever is being piped through it?

Comment: Can you amend the program to use the `fd` of `/dev/tty` rather than that of `stdout`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Hmm. And is /dev/tty different for every process depending on what terminal it's on?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is specific to each process.

Answer (score 2):

You have more than one choice:

- there are three streams (*stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr*), which your program can check using `isatty(fileno(stdin))`, etc.  Redirecting output for an interactive program is more often done than redirecting input, so it is worth checking that.
- if none of the streams is a terminal, you can open the `tty` which is associated with every *interactive* process.  That is not necessarily `/dev/tty`, as shown in a quick check from a shell running in `xterm`:

```
    $ ls -l /dev/tty;tty;ls -l `tty`
    crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 0 Mar 10 15:46 /dev/tty
    /dev/pts/1
    crw--w---- 1 tom tty 136, 1 Mar 10 16:09 /dev/pts/1
```

- POSIX documents the [`tty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tty.html) program which might seem a good place to start.  However your program would have to read the pathname from a pipe (a little more complicated than `isatty` applied to the standard streams).  The documentation also says

  > While no input is read from standard input, standard input shall be examined to determine whether or not it is a terminal, and, if so, to determine the name of the terminal.

  That is, if your program's standard input is redirected (not a terminal), `tty` is of no help finding the real terminal.
  Comment by @einpoklum reminded me that POSIX also documents the library call [`ttyname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ttyname.html). By the way, usually when a program is implemented by a particular function call, POSIX documents the program, saying that it behaves "as if" if it used that call.  But it did not mention this for `tty`.
- if none of the standard streams is a terminal, you *could* try opening `/dev/tty`.  If your program is not interactive, that could fail, e.g., running in `cron` or in the background.  Lest that seem an odd criticism, there are occasional requests to open an X application from `cron`.  Again, POSIX documents that (in [10.1 Directory Structure and Files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html)

Comment: POSIX tty is not a good place to start, it just makes the `ttyname()` library call and prints the result (I checked the sources). But trying all 3 file descriptors is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are suggestions to try /dev/stderr , /dev/stdout, and /dev/stdin to see which one works, falling back on /dev/tty if none of them point to a terminal.

This is pointless. They will fail if they are redirected or piped, but otherwise will direct to /dev/tty

It's basically saying "check these until one points to /dev/tty, if not, try another, if all tried, resort to trying /dev/tty

If you want the size of the terminal, use /dev/tty directly.

The only reason to check the others first would be if you want to test whether they are going to screen.

P.S. I'm not allowed to leave a comment, but can leave a reply. Weird.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit strange that new users have to answer in order to leave comments. I see your point though.